# $location.path is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm working frontend using AngularJS v.1.3.15

In my controller, I add $location to

```
app.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($location) {}
```

but in my function, i'm using

```
$location.path('/search').search($scope.search_params);`
```

and i received error:

> $location.path is not a function

and only occurs in a few times, not often, but when it happened, it will always cause errors

Comment: Did you try to inject `$location` into your controller: `app.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {}])` ?

Comment: I doubt that's the entire controller definition, since you couldn't possibly use `$scope` in that call if you didn't inject it into the controller along with `$location`.  My guess is that you actually have more than this being injected, are using the array initialization syntax, and have the number of arguments out of whack.

Comment: as @Claies says, there must be some typo in order or number of parameters. try to output : console.log(arguments); in your controller

Comment: @TeoMor: I found that my code and your anything different?